# Missing operating system when computer restarts

Tags: boot

When I restart my computer, it says "Missing operating system", but when I shut it down and turn it back on again, it works fine. I only receive the message when I press the "restart" button. If I shut it down and turn it on manually, the system works as it should. It is not a major problem since I can get it to work, but I would still like to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a complex issue, can you look around and see if there are any error logs anywhere?

Comment: BIOS hard disk pre-delay could be at fault - or having a USB hard drive plugged in could introduce weirdness that exhibits a lot like this.  Either way, it's hardware dependent.

Comment: I do have a flash drive plugged in. I'll check if that's it.

Comment: Yep, it was the flash drive. When I restart without it, it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIOS hard disk pre-delay could be at fault - or having a USB hard drive plugged in could introduce weirdness that exhibits a lot like this.

Either way, it's hardware dependent.